# Regex stops after match and does not match further when using Alternation symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to fix this since yesterday and believe I am missing something very simple.

I wrote a regex to match ANY ONE of the three IP address format:

```
Pattern to match : X.X.X.X OR X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X OR X.X.X.X-X.X.X.X
```

**Regex:**

```
/^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\/([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\-([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))$/
```

**Problem:**

The regex matches the above 3 formats but the problem is with the **alternation** **symbol** - the behaviour is like the regex stops once the match is found.

```
Example: 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1 - Once this match is found it does not check after that.

i.e: 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1 - Valid 

 But 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1(...anything after this is also recognized as valid which should not be the case...)
```

**Question:**

How do I make it to match only one of the 3 alternatives as it is. I tried a bit with `word boundaries (\b)` as well, but I am not sure if that is what is needed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$)|(^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[\/-](?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$)
```

You can test it using the following link for verification.

https://regex101.com/r/fC6uS3/1

Comment: Wonderful!. Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. I Could you also add some explanation (a single line would suffice) as to how it works and what my regex was missing?

Comment: Glad that I could be of help. The explanation part related to the regex can be seen on right hand side of the link provided (regex101). Coming to what your regex was missing may be I can't do that now. But, will let you know for sure when I have time.

Comment: Yes..got it. Thanks for your time @Vamsi!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that alternation has the lowest precedence of all the regex constructs.  Your regex matches either:

```
^X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X    // anchored at start only
```

or

```
X.X.X.X-X.X.X.X     // not anchored
```

or

```
X.X.X.X$            // anchored at end only
```

You can fix it by adding another set of parentheses around everything but the anchors:

```
^(your regex)$
```

Comment: Cool..if I add an extra paranthesis to my regex, it works too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you want to match more than one, but if that is the case then remove "^" from the beginning and "$" from the end and also make it globally search like this:

```
/(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\/([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\-([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))/g
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem still persists. I want the regex to recognize 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1(...anything after this as Invalid.....). But since it matches 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1 it does not care to match beyond that.

Comment: Ow did not read carefully enogh. But have you tried the regex I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably shorten your regex to:

```
^(((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))))([/-](((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}(([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))))*$
```

If you are running it with javascript you would surround with `/.../`

```js
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))))([/-](((([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}(([0-2][0-5][0-6])|(\d{1,2}))))*$/);
var testCases = {};

//should work
testCases['testCaseA'] = '1.2.3.4';
testCases['testCaseB'] = '1.2.3.4/1.256.3.4';
testCases['testCaseC'] = '1.2.3.4-1.2.3.4';

//should not work
testCases['testCaseD'] = '1.257.3.4';
testCases['testCaseE'] = '1.2.3.4/1.2.3.356';
testCases['testCaseF'] = '1.2.3.4-1.2.3.4I';
var results = '<table><tr><th>Cases</th><th>Inputs</th><th>Outputs</th></tr>';
$.each(testCases, function(k, v) {
results += '<tr><td>' + k + '&emsp;&emsp;</td><td>' + v + '&emsp;&emsp;</td><td>' + pattern.test(v) + '</td>';
});
document.write(results + '</table>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This matches 256.256.256.256 as well

Comment: I do not have problem with the regex for numbers..I intend to match a specific set of numbers ..but the problem is stated above. For simplification , I have used 1.1.1.1.1 as an example.

Comment: @Moishe - I do not have any problem with defining what `X` should be in `X.X.X.X` format. But as you will see I want `X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X` to be valid and not `X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X(..any symbol after this..)`

Comment: I just want to say that it rejects a valid ip address.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks for pointing out. I missed that initially, but it should now work.